# check input data if it exist in firebase before adding it

Tags: reactjs

I have input text where I write username and a button that I click to add this username to database of firebase using react
it's works fine and this is my code:

this is the functions that I handle when write and click:

```
    onSubmitInputChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            usernameValue: event.target.value
        });
    }

    onSubmit(event) {
                firebase.firestore().collection('readers').add({
                  email: this.state.usernameValue
                })
        }
```

and this is the input and button code in render:

```
<SubscribeBox
       onChange={this.onSubmitInputChange.bind(this)}
       value={this.state.usernameValue} placeholder="email address" />

<Button onClick={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
 ADD
</Button>
```

it works fine and the username added to firebase when ever i write something in input then click button
but I want to add username only if it doesn't exist in firebase so how can I check each username before add it to firebase in order to not get duplicate usernames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before adding user to firebase, request a query using the mail and check for any results:

```
onSubmit(event) {


    firebase.firestore().collection('readers').where("email", "==", this.state.usernameValue).get().then((resultSnapShot) => {

        // resultSnapShot is an array of docs where "email" === "user_mail"

        if (resultSnapShot.size == 0) {
            //Proceed

            firebase.firestore().collection('readers').add({
                email: this.state.usernameValue
            })

        } else {
            //Already registered
            console.log("User exists!!!")
        }

    })

}
```

Comment: I got this error: `_firebase.default.firestore(...).collection(...).where(...).then is not a function` @Karlo A. López

Comment: Sorry I missed a `.get().` method before calling `then()`, please check my updated answer

Comment: thanks bro easy to understand and working perfect @Karlo A. López

Answer (score 0):

```
ref.child("readers").orderByChild("email").equalTo(usernameValue).once("value",snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.exists()){
      const userData = snapshot.val();
      console.log("exists!", userData);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is that a question? If so, then it should be posted as one.

Comment: @Andronicus I have improved my answer.